# Memory leak in C hash table implementation

Tags: c, memory-leaks, hashtable

I have implemented a hash table structure as follows (reads all words from a text files, and contructs a hash table and then prints all the values of the table on a single line):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int hashf(const char *buf, size_t len) {
    unsigned int h = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h += buf[i];
        h += h << 10;
        h ^= h >> 7;
    }
    h += h << 3;
    h ^= h >> 11;
    h += h << 15;
    return h;
}

void destroy_hash(char *hashtable[], int table_size) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<table_size; i++) {
        if (hashtable[i]) {
            free(hashtable[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Invalid parameters!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    int table_size = atoi(argv[2]);

    char *hashtable[table_size];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < table_size; i++) {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }
    unsigned int h, h_k;

    FILE *fileread = fopen(filename, "r");

    char *key;
    char buf[100];
    int probe_nro, word_nro = 0;

    if (fileread) {

        fscanf(fileread, "%99s", buf);
        key = malloc((strlen(buf)+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(key, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
        while(!feof(fileread)) {
            // Increase word_nro by 1
            word_nro += 1;
            if (word_nro <= table_size) {
                h = hashf(key, strlen(buf)) % table_size;
                if (!hashtable[h]) {
                    hashtable[h] = key;
                }
                else {
                    // Begin probing
                    probe_nro = 1;
                    // Save original hash to h_k:
                    h_k = h;

                    h = (h_k+(probe_nro*probe_nro)) % table_size;

                    while (hashtable[h] && (probe_nro <= 10000)) {
                        probe_nro += 1;
                        h = (h_k+(probe_nro*probe_nro)) % table_size;
                    }
                    // If no vacancy found after 10000 probes, return error
                    if (probe_nro == 10000) {
                        printf("Error: table full\n");
                        free(key);
                        destroy_hash(hashtable, table_size);
                        return(1);
                    }
                    hashtable[h] = key;
                }
                fscanf(fileread, "%99s", buf);
                if (!feof(fileread)) {
                    key = malloc((strlen(buf)+1)*sizeof(char));
                    memcpy(key, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
                }
            }
        else {
            free(key);
            printf("Error: table full\n");
            destroy_hash(hashtable, table_size);
            return(1);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i < table_size; i++) {
        if (hashtable[i]) {
            printf("%s", hashtable[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if (i < table_size - 1) {
            printf(",");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    destroy_hash(hashtable, table_size);
}
else    {
    printf("Can't open file!\n");
    return(1);
}
return(0);
}
```

I can't find the memory leak, which is indicated in valgrind as:
total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 604 bytes allocated
still reachable: 568 bytes in 1 blocks

Can you maybe spot, what I should still free, or what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
if (!feof(fileread)) {
    key = malloc((strlen(buf)+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(key, buf, strlen(buf) + 1); // <--
}
```

You are making `key` point to a new location without freeing the old memory you allocated with `malloc`. It should be

```
if (!feof(fileread)) {
    free(key); // <--
    key = malloc((strlen(buf)+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(key, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
}
```

Comment: This will fail because it tries to free before the first malloc was performed. Instead, change the declaration to initialize key to NULL, and make the free() call conditional.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: If I add that, I get "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: @mah: Can you be more exact: where should I set key to NULL?

Comment: @rize when you initialise it: `char* key = NULL;`

Comment: @mah can you explain that? It looks like, by the time that code is reached, the line `key = malloc((strlen(buf)+1)*sizeof(char));` is run (just under `if (fileread) {`)

Comment: Ok, I set char* key = NULL; and then if (key) { free(key) }, but I still get "pointer being freed was not allocated", trying to debug that..

Comment: @rize you don't have to do `if (key) free(key);` because you can call `free` on a `NULL` pointer and it will be perfectly fine and do nothing. The problem comes when `key` is not `NULL` _and_ it points to some memory that was not allocated with `malloc` (or was allocated by `malloc` but was already `free`d) and you call `free` on it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie ok, changed that, thanks. So I think, mostly likely then key is set to point to some memory not allocated with malloc. Is the memcpy(key, buf, strlen(buf) + 1); fine? So, it copies memory from location buf to location key, it doesn't change key itself, right?

Comment: @rize yes, that looks fine to me. Again, I don't know what mah is talking about since you `malloc` the memory before you `free` it with my suggestion, and when I run your code I don't get an error.

Comment: Actually, it's really weird: I'm locally on a mac, and with ssh on a ubuntu, and on my mac, I end up having all to slots of the hash table, which are filled, point to the same memory location (or so it seems, because it prints the same word from every hash slot), AND I ran into "pointer being freed was not allocated", WHEREAS on the ubuntu, no erros arise, when I run the code, and it seems to do exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: So, it turned out, I forgot fclose(fileread) at the end :) A friend, who looked at the code quickly with no hope of correcting it, mentioned this :) What do they say about becoming blind to your own code... Anyway, there is still a minor leak, if the table becomes full, but that will easily be fixed, I hope.

Comment: @rize ah, I am used to C++ where you don't have to close files :) (because of RAII)

Comment: Any idea, from where the memory leaks, reported in Valgrind as "Heap summary: still use at exit ... Definately lost: ..." come from? Only a few bytes are leaked anymore. And that only happens, when the table is too small, so "word_nro <= table_size" is not satisfied.

Comment: @rize step through the code and note all `malloc`s on a piece of paper, then check them off as they are `free`d. You'll have a non-checked `malloc` somewhere and that's your memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

```
void destroy_hash(char *hashtable[], int table_size) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<table_size; i++) {
        if (hashtable[i]) {
            free(hashtable[i]);
            hashtable[i] = NULL; /* this one ? */
        }
    }
}
```